# How to change the selected name of a doctrine querybuilder expression inside of a select

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-query

I am trying to change the returned array from a doctrine query from:

```
['city' => 'Warsaw', '1' => '2']
```

to:

```
['city' => 'Warsaw', 'count' => '2']
```

My query looks like this:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('geo');
$queryBuilder->select([
    'geo.city',
    $queryBuilder->expr()->countDistinct('geo.id')
]);
$queryBuilder->groupBy('geo.city');
$result = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Not sure how to correctly write a `AS count` into this subexpression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Expr class is nothing more than a set of helpers to write your expressions. Nothing prevents you from combining it with strings:

```php
// $qb your query builder
$qb->addSelect($qb->expr()->countDistinct('geo.id') . ' AS geo_count');
```

If you don't like mixing expr and strings, you could even write the DQL directly:

```php
$qb->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT geo.id) AS geo_count');
```

*Note: I used `geo_count` as the alias since you can't use `count` as it will be interpreted as the `COUNT` function by the DQL parser.*

Comment: I was looking for something like `countDistinct('geo.id')->as(geo_count)`, but your solution works well, although it would be nice to avoid the stringiness of both solution. Thanks!

Comment: @tobias47n9e Yeah I was searching for the same [in the doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class) but the `expr` class's `countDistinct` method only expect one argument and there is no `as` method as you can see. I guess someone could try to implement it and send a PR for that :)